# My wrist controller is angled oddly

Tags: rigging

I want the controller to be more aligned with the hand.
Anyone know how to fix it?
[image]
here is a [image]

using the cutting edge software update

Comment: Please mention when you are using Blender 2.8. Since it is still an unreleased, unstable, beta version: a lot of people don't even have it, don't open files with it by default or don't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your hand controller is rotated, because your metarig doesn't produce that. You might have done something we don't know to get that. Fixing it manually might take some time.

However, since you're using Rigify and that your metarig seem to be correct, it will be quite simple: regenerate your rig from your metarig and it will be fixed.

For that, select your metarig object. Then in the object data tab, head over to the `Rigify Buttons` panel, usually located at the very bottom. You will just need to change the target object in your meshes's Armature Deform modifiers for them to be deformed by your new rig. The skinning should remain intact.
If you want to generate a new rig, simply hit the <kbd>Generate Rig</kbd> button.
If you want to override your already existing rig, hit the <kbd>Advanced Options</kbd> button first, set it up like the following and then hit the <kbd>Generate Rig</kbd> button:

[image: Rigify Advanced Options setup]
No need for modifiers retargeting this time.